# How can I write the java console output in Excel sheet in same format

Tags: java

I am getting console output as below, I want to print in same format in Excel sheet. How can I do this?

```
Group ID       Group Name             Organization ID  Organization Type User Limit    
GP00000517001  SIPtest Site hostpool  SIP00000517      Enterprise            
GP8566747001   SIT mars test SIP te   SIP8566747       Enterprise
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried with using POI.

Comment: Well, edit your question and show the code that you have tried, and explain what the problem with it was.

Comment: Frankly speaking, i am very new to java & selenium too.Just trying to learn.As i mentioned above, My java console looking like same. Only i want to print it in Excel sheet.

Comment: Which means you have to read documentation, do small practice tasks, and learn the tools which you are using. If you are looking for ready-made answers, StackOverflow is not the place.

Comment: http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use JExcelapi or apache POI, or any other library that is able to create excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this sample code to print your console text into excel.
Only thing you have to taken into consideration is that you have to print your text using delimters i.e comma(,).

```
int i = 0;
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\testconsole.csv")));
        System.setOut(printStream);
        while(i<1000){
            System.out.print(i+++","+i+++","+i++);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Please run above code you will get the idea. how you will achieve your scenario.

Comment: appreciate your comments, what ever you say, it's correct to create excel sheet, My Question is- In my Eclipse suppose i am getting some out put as "9399" prem , Address      ,The same out put i wants to print in a excel.

Comment: I have changed the answer as per your requirement.Please let me know if you still have any issue.

Comment: Thanks, i got some idea from your code & now it's working, i am using below code                                                                      List<WebElement> groupIdList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id*='Col0']"));
           PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\testconsole.csv")));
           System.setOut(printStream);
           for (int i=0; i < groupIdList.size(); i++){
               System.out.print(groupIdList.get(i1).getText());
               System.setOut(printStream);
           }

Comment: I am getting the out as below in Excel sheet

GP00000517001GP00000532001GP201TNatt2sai285001GP201TNorder285sa001GP201TNorder3sai001
How can i split it, it should display like below data ?
GP00000517001
GP00000532001
GP201TNatt2sai285001

Comment: replace with these:                         System.out.print(groupIdList.get(i1).getText());
System.out.println();